# Are there other ways to use Hue----not a must need to add a Linux username as the same as Hue username?

Tags: impala, cloudera-cdh, sentry, hue

When using CDH 6.3.x-Hue by Sentry to control the access privilege of my impala datas, I find that the hue username must be a Linux username！
It's not elegant，So what shall I do to avoid to create username of Linux？ Use Hue by its username directly？

Answer (score 0):

When you use Kerberos, there is no other way as it would defeat the purpose of security.

https://docs.gethue.com/administrator/configuration/server/#authentication

Comment: Hue user should be created，but I don‘t want to create a same user of Linux！It looks not good because every server need do it，otherwise Hue user doesn't work ！

Answer (score 0):

I only use Sentry with Hue to control the access of kudu,used impala query;
At last ,I found that Hue user must be created，and only Impala Coordinator Server is needed to do the thing--to create a same user of Hue on the server  at the first!

Comment: useradd -g *groupname* *HueUsername* ------on the  impala coordinator server